# Logarithm problem : Prove that $log_{3^2} \frac{1}{2} > 0$

Tags: inequality, logarithms

Logarithm problem :

Prove that $log_{3^2} \frac{1}{2} > 0$

My approach :

$log_{3^2} \frac{1}{2} > 0$

$\Rightarrow \frac{1}{2} log_3 \frac{1}{2} >0$

$\Rightarrow \frac{1}{2} [ log_3 1 -log_3 2] >0                  $

$\Rightarrow \frac{1}{2} [ 0 - log_3 2] >0                   $

$\Rightarrow -\frac{1}{2} [  log_3 2] > 0                   $ { which is false}

Please suggest... thanks...

Comment: The base 9 log of 1/2 isn't greater than zero…

Answer (score 2):

It is hard to prove something that isn't true.  [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=log%289,1/2%29) shows $\log_9 \frac 12 \lt -0.3$ so you aren't even close.  Generally, logs of things less than $1$ are negative.

Answer (score 1):

To evaluate $log_{3^2}\frac{1}{2}$ you solve $(3^2)^x=\frac{1}{2} \rightarrow xlog(3^2)=log(\frac{1}{2}) \rightarrow x =\frac{log(\frac{1}{2})}{log(3^2)}$, but $log(\frac{1}{2}) = -ln(2)$. Hence,  $log_{3^2}\frac{1}{2}$ is not greater than 0.

Comment: A language nit:  you don't solve $\log_{3^2} \frac 12$, you evaluate it.  The claim that it is less than $0$ is correct.  In $\LaTeX$, if you precede log with a backslash, you get the correct font.  So \log gives $\log$

Comment: Yes this is true.

Comment: Who cares about the font.

Comment: I do, and I suspect I am not alone.  Functions are supposed to be set in an upright font, while variables are italic.  The standard ones are defined so you can just put a backslash before the name.  If you have a non-standard one, you can do \operatorname {function}, but I admit that I don't bother.  Do what you like.